# Error Calling a JAVA web service after Windows Update KB3147458

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, saxparseexception

Some weeks ago, our team installed an application that calls a webservice (https://palena.sii.cl/DTEWS/CrSeed.jws?wsdl) on a Windows 10 Machine. Weeks later, the windows update installed a critical security update (KB3147458) and the application stop working as intended. This is the error:

[image]

The first thing i did. It was to check the enconding of the XML sended by the application. Unfortunately, the file was using UTF-8 without BOM and from that moment i couldn't figure out whats the cause of the error. This is the output file:

[image]

[image]

Im writting because i need your help to figure out whats the problem. If you want to reproduce it, add the WSDL (https://palena.sii.cl/DTEWS/CrSeed.jws?wsdl) as a WebReference and call the **getSeed** method, using an updated Windows 10.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem... Until now I only found two possible solutions:

Uninstall the KB3147458 and try again.
Update you application to Framework 4.6.

There is a SSLStream break... More Info here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2590316/windows-10-update-kb3147458-changes-behavior-of-sslstream-read-beginread-endread

Comment: Changing the target Framework to 4.6.1 solves the problem for me. Thank you!